# Programmatically detemine if a query is legacy or SQL 2011 syntax?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi is there a way to programmatically detect if a query string is in the legacy or SQL-2011 syntax? I know the former uses `[project:dataset.table]` for table references while the later uses `` `project.dataset.table` `` but this doesn't seem very bullet proof.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to tell just from the query text in all cases, which is why BigQuery has the "Use Legacy SQL" checkbox in the UI and the `use_legacy_sql` option for the query API. For example, consider this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 AS x), (SELECT 2), (SELECT 3);
```

The results are very different despite the query being valid in both dialects.

Standard SQL queries can still contain `[]`, too, such as for array literals.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming query is syntax-wise correct and expected to actually work -  you can do [Dry Run](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.dryRun) using both options ([Legacy and Standard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.useLegacySql)) and see which fails and which not. Based on result you can potentially derive the answer